# device_list is not shown

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an api where the list of groups are shown along with the devices id that falls under that groups. For example if there is a device named Speedometer, Humidifier and they fall under Home group then my api should include

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Home"
  "device_list": [
    {
      "id": "b45c56ioxa1"
    },
    {
      "id": "h4oc2d5ofa9"
    }
  ]
},
```

but my code does not produce device_list in the api. It only shows name and id

device_list is the list of all the devices id that are in a certain group.

**Here is my code**

```
class DeviceIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id')

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    device_list = DeviceIdSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False, source="groups")
    class Meta:
       model = DeviceGroup
       fields = ('id', 'name', 'device_list')

class DevicesGroupsAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
            Returns a list of groups
        """
        reply = {}
        try:
            groups = DeviceGroup.objects.all()
            print ('reply', groups)
            reply['data'] = DeviceGroupSerializer(groups, many=True).data
        except:
            reply['data'] = []
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

class BaseDevice(PolymorphicModel):
    # User's own identifier of the product
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    # Any device should have a owner, right from the creation
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey('DeviceGroup', related_name="groups", null=True, blank=True)

class Device(BaseDevice):
  description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: device_list is not mapped to any model data... maybe map it to group

Comment: i have mapped it to group as groups = DeviceIdSerializer() but i get empty data object now.

Comment: I meant setting the source like `device_list = DeviceIdSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False, source='groups')` so that the serializer knows where to fetch the data from. Source needs to be a field, property or callable on the object, so you might need to try different things like 'groups.all'

Comment: I have updated my questions by updating serializers. I still get empty data object.

Comment: by groups.all do you mean to say get all the groups given a device. Can you show me an example of what you are saying, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out the very same code you have except I used `models.Model` as the base model.
The first time I got an error

> The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "**all**". Got str.
>   which clearly states where your problem is.
>   So I changed class the fields option in DeviceIdSerializer

```
DeviceIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id',)
```

Note that I've added a comma (",") which makes fields a tuple instead of a string as it was before.
Now the data I get is

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"test",
   "device_list":[
      {
         "id":"38ec7e152f9d49a38008c859a1022525"
      },
      {
         "id":"b0d799509260474cb092899ef84ce49c"
      },
      {
         "id":"e5c7cf8f9f5043c68c34c7b962569b08"
      }
   ]
}
```

which is the same as what you are looking for...

Comment: I included the name field and it showed me the result i wanted. I did find the solution by myself but did not know how it worked. Your answer helped me to understand and i thank you very much. I am marking your answer as solved.

Comment: Can you please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545648/post-group-name-with-the-multiple-device-selected ? when i hit localhost:8000/device_group/device_id i dont get form to post so that i can check if its working or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think your serializers need to look like this:

```
class DeviceIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id')

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    groups = DeviceIdSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'groups')
```

Or change this:

```
class BaseDevice(PolymorphicModel):
    # User's own identifier of the product
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    # Any device should have a owner, right from the creation
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=False, null=False)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey('DeviceGroup', related_name="device_list", null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I tried with the groups but i get empty data object. I mean the first way.