# post group name with the multiple device selected

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an api for device group and device. A device group can have multiple devices and i want to have the post api for device group with multiple devices because group creation is shown only when device is selected and user might select multiple devices and then create a new group. That way when group is created, those selected devices should also be shown as device_list

Here is my code, i am not sure on how to do post request

```
class BaseDevice(PolymorphicModel):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
  group = models.ForeignKey('DeviceGroup', related_name="groups", null=True, blank=True)

class Device(BaseDevice):
  description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)  

class DeviceIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        # id is the token of the device and name is the name of the device
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    device_list = DeviceIdSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False, source="groups")
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        # name is the name of group created and device_list is the list of devices with id(token) and device name
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'device_list')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print ('validated_data', validated_data)
        device_list_data = validated_data.pop('device_list')
        group = DeviceGroup.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for device_list in device_list_data:
            BaseDevice.objects.create(group=group, **device_list)
        return group

class DeviceGroupAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self, user, token):
        try:
            return BaseDevice.objects.filter(owner=user).get(token=token)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()


    def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        device_group_instance = DeviceGroup.objects.get(token=token)
        for device_token in request.data['devices']:
            device = Device.objects.get(token=device_token, owner=request.user)
            device.group = device_group_instance
```

Here is my api design

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Home",
         "device_list":[
            {
               "id":"481cfef5a4884e52a63d135967fbc367",
               "name":"Oxygen Provider"
            },
            {
               "id":"7eb006d6db50479aa47f887da0d4f10e",
               "name":"Fan Speed"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Business",
         "device_list":[

         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
url(r'^device_group/(?P<token>[0-9a-f]+)/add$', DeviceGroupAPIView.as_view(), name='device_group'),
```

Comment: does it create the group & devices properly? Is any error thrown? The instance you pass should be a DeviceGroup or None, but not a Device

Comment: Sorry i could not test it as the form is not shown in browsable api.

Comment: i get the form now but media type and content type of form is shown. The instance of DeviceGroup? i did not understand that

Comment: Few things to point out: Your device is dependent on a group being present. You cannot create a device and then a group. You could follow the django admin approach and allow to add a new group while adding a device OR change you models to allow a device to be created first. Also DRF has viewsets which might make it easier for you. I don't understand why a token is needed to add a group. I'll try writing some code for you, but you should read up more on DRF and how to write proper APIs

Comment: token is the id of the device in my case and it is needed to post group in that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a bit

```
class BaseDevice(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey('DeviceGroup', related_name="groups", null=True, blank=True)

class Device(BaseDevice):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)

class DeviceIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(source='token', format='hex', read_only=True)
    # token does not exist in your model so this will not be included
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        # id is the token of the device and name is the name of the device
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class DeviceGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    device_list = DeviceIdSerializer(read_only=False, many=True, required=False, source="groups")
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceGroup
        # name is the name of group created and device_list is the list of devices with id(token) and device name
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'device_list')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print ('validated_data', validated_data)
        device_list_data = validated_data.pop('groups', [])
        # notice that I pop 'groups' because validation changes the input data 
        # to match the field names
        # Also since it is not required I've added a default value
        group = DeviceGroup.objects.create(**validated_data)
        devices = [BaseDevice(group=group, **device_list) for device_list in device_list_data] 
        BaseDevice.objects.bulk_create(devices)
        # Use bulk create when you have to create multiple objects
        # It hits the db only once instead of multiple times
        return group

class DeviceGroupAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = DeviceGroupSerializer
    queryset = DeviceGroup.objects.all()
    # Although I have used ModelViewSet, you could use any other one
    # I used this so that I don't need to write the code for create,
    # update, delete or list


# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'device_group', DeviceGroupAPIView, base_name='device_group')
# this gives the following urls
# /device_group/ POST to create, GET to list    
# /device_group/(?<pk>\d+)/  GET to retrieve single DeviceGroup, PATCH/PUT to update it, and DELETE to delete it
```

This is the structure of the JSON to POST to create a new DeviceGroup with a bunch of Devices

```
{
   "name":"Group Name",
   "device_list":[
      {
         "name":"Device 1"
      },
      {
         "name":"Device 2"
      },
      {
         "name":"Device 3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Hope this helps

Also you should read up more about [Django-Rest-Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have one last question. you told to send the instance of devicegroup to DeviceGroupSerializer so i changed my post function. Is that what you were saying? As a beginner i dont want to use ModelViewSet so i tried to use APIView. Can you please look into my post function only?

Comment: Your DeviceGroup does not have a field called token, so you cannot use that to perform lookups. But if you had DeviceGroup object the way you're assigning is good enough (with a `.save()`). If this is your first Django project, you might want to put it on hold and try few tutorials first

Comment: I have the token field in DeviceGroup as token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False).

Comment: if my posting is right, can you update your answer with my post function. I will mark this as answered and thanks for the suggestion. I am poor in understanding English which troubles me a lot to grasp the concept

Comment: My answer doesn't need a `post()` method as the one in the base class is enough, and the serializer `create()` does everything that's needed. Your `post()` on the other hand doesn't use serializers at all. It expects the group token in the url, and device tokens in the data (I didn't have anything in the url). So both codes should work independently